# How scroll to top if header is fixed?

Tags: jquery

I have code

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

But I have fixed header on top with height 50px. So I stop before top. I tried  $(document).scrollTop(-50) but it didnt help. How to solve this problem?

**Sorry, I hadnt attention. I used scroll for another element. The problem is solved. It works.**

Comment: If you want to stop **before** reaching the top, shouldn't you use a positive value, like `.scrollTop(50)`?

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, I hadnt attention. I used scroll for another element. The problem is solved. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-top: 50px` to the CSS of the first element in the regular document flow. This creates a vertical distance of 50px which keeps your content below the fixed header.

Comment: I have padding-top: 50px;

Comment: <div id="header> //height 50px     <div id="noheader> //padding-top: 50px

Comment: Sorry, I hadnt attention. I used scroll for another element. The problem is solved. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
Var fixedheader = $("HEADER")
Var pos = fixedheader.offset()
Var scrollpos = fixedheader.outeheight() + fixedheader.top. 
//And then 
$(document).scrollTop(scrollpos)
```

Scrollpos have the exact position of the buttom for the header

Comment: Sorry, I hadnt attention. I used scroll for another element. The problem is solved. It works.